# Swagger 2.0 generated aspnetcore model and EF Core database first approach generated model

Tags: database, model, swagger, ef-core-2.0

I have generated aspnetcore code from swagger 2.0 which generates the model classes as well. My question is here the model generated in this and the model generated from EF Core with Database first approach will be different here.
I need to know is this the best way to have different models for almost same entities or should this be combined in some way, that is; the the model generated from swagger and the database model for ef core 2.0 can be combined somwhow?

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: @Artem thanks for your response.
I got a solution to my question, Using Data transfer objects (DTO) instead of the actual database model would be a better option.
Ref - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5

Comment: You can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Data transfer objects (DTO) instead of the actual database model would be a better option.
Ref - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5